# Ajuda em Sql que consulta 2 campos da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, join

Tenho o seguinte problema para resolver:

Preciso fazer um Sql que consulte uma tabela X

```
"Tabela X":
id coluna1 coluna2 

"Tabela 2":
id coluna1 coluna2 coluna3.
```

Na "Tabela X" coluna1 e coluna2 são chaves estrangeira da "tabela 2" ambas com valores diferentes.

No Sql preciso retornar o id da tabelaX o id da tabela 2 e uma coluna qualquer da tabela dois para os 2 campos de chave estrangeira.

Exempo de dados:

```
Tabela X:

id   coluna1     coluna2   
1     1           2
2     2           1           
3     3           1
4     4           2
```

coluna1 e coluna 2 é são chave primaria da tabela 2.

```
Tabela 2:

id    coluna1       coluna2      coluna 3
1     TB2val1      TB2outro1     TB2aux1
2     TB2val2      TB2outro2     TB2aux2 
3     TB2val3      TB2outro3     TB2aux3
4     TB2val4      TB2outro4     TB2aux4
```

Tentei fazer assim:

```
select  tx.id,tx.coluna1,tx.coluna2,t2.coluna1   from tabelaX tx,tabela2 t2 
where tx.id=t2.id group by tx.id,tx.coluna1,tx.coluna2,t2
```

mas não consegui completar o sql pois preciso unir a outra consulta  no select e não consegui achar como faz isso.

Eu precisaria de um retorno no select com essas colunas:

```
idTabela1   idTabela2 idTabela2  tabela2.coluna1  tabela2.coluna1
```

No primeiro resultado teria que ficar assim:

Resultado da primeira linha do select que eu preciso:   `1    1    2   TB2val1   TB2val2`

Dei uma pesquisada aqui e provavelmente esta questão se resolve com um Union select.

Comment: `tabela2.coluna1  tabela2.coluna1` o mesmo campo 2x ?

Answer (score 0):

Como `coluna1` e `coluna2` são chave primária e estrangeira em `tabelaX` e `tabela2`, respectivamente, você precisa utilizar esses campos no [**JOIN**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

```
SELECT 
    tx.id as idTabela1, t2.id as idTabela2, tx.coluna1 as coluna1, tx.coluna2 as coluna2
FROM 
    tabelaX tx
JOIN 
    tabela2 t2 ON tx.coluna1 = t2.coluna1 AND tx.coluna2 = t2.coluna2
```

Comment: deste modo só vai aparecer t2.coluna2

Comment: Não é está consulta que eu quero fazer, eu quero retornar a mesma coluna t2.coluna1 no entanto para os 2 fks diferentes, tipo o exemplo que editei.

Comment: Lembro me que existem maneiras de  unir 2 selects quando é necessário selecionar o mesmo campo mas que pertençam a  ids  diferentes

Comment: acho que não entendi bem qual o problema

Comment: mas se as ids são diferentes e você quer unir os resultados, tira o id da exibição..

Comment: o importante são os campos tabela2.coluna1 , mesmo que eu tire  os  ids, esses outros 2 sempre serão diferentes pois são de registros diferentes.

Comment: pelo que entendi, `coluna1` é igual nas duas tabelas (assim como `coluna2`), já que eles são chaves.. sendo assim, não entendi o ponto que está com problema

Comment: Coluna 1 e Coluna 2 na tabelaX são referencias para o mesmo campo na tabela2 mas na tabelaX elas possuem valores diferentes exemplo 1 e 2 ou seja referenciam 2 registros diferentes e em cada um desses registros há um valor em "coluna1" da tabela2

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi o que você está querendo, você pode utilizar um simples **JOIN**:

```
SELECT tx.id AS "TabelaX ID", t2.id AS "Tabela2 ID", t2.coluna1, t2.coluna2 FROM TabelaX tx JOIN Tabela2 t2 ON (tx.coluna1 = t2.id OR tx.coluna2 = t2.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Analisando o resultado esperado que você mencionou, eu acho que da para resolver usando subqueries no select, não consegui ver uma forma usando union, join ou from nas duas tabelas como você tentou fazer.

```sql
select
    x.id,
    x.coluna1,
    x.coluna2,
    (
        select coluna1 
        from tabela2 t2 
        where x.coluna1 = t2.id 
        limit 1
    ) as coluna1val,
    (
        select coluna1 
        from tabela2 t2 
        where x.coluna2 = t2.id 
        limit 1
    ) as coluna2val
from tabelaX x
```